# How do I convert strings in an array to numbers using forEach?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to sum the contents of an array like these:

var cardsBen  =  [10,2]

var cardsAmy  =  [4,10]

When I use a for loop, it works.

```
for(var i = 0; i < cardsBen.length; i++){
  cardsBen[i] = Number(cardsBen[i]);
}
```

When I use forEach, it doesn't convert.

```
cardsAmy.forEach(function(item)
  {
    Number(item);
  });
```

I know this because, when I then reduce the arrays, I get 12 for Ben and 410 for Amy.

```
var sumBen = cardsBen.reduce(function(sum, nbr){return sum + nbr});
var sumAmy = cardsAmy.reduce(function(sum, nbr){return sum + nbr});
```

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: What exactly do you think happens to the result of `Number(item)`?

Comment: you still have numbers, no `Number` required.

Comment: you can use `+sum + +nbr`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primitive values can't be mutated. So when doing `Number(item)` you have to assign that back to the array like:

```
cardsAmy.forEach(function(item, i) {
    cardsAmy[i] = Number(item);
});
```

And you can do that directly in `reduce` (without needing the above `forEach` code) like:

```
var sumBen = cardsBen.reduce(function(sum, nbr) { return sum + Number(nbr); }, 0);
//                                                             ^^^^^^^   ^
```

Comment: Yes - That's it. Thanks. Can't click the check mark for 3 minutes.

Comment: Best response would include an initial value to `reduce`. Try again with `var cardsBen = []` and see,,,

Comment: @RaphaMex Good point! Added an initial value. Although I don't think it will be necessary (in this case).

Comment: At this point, I am just trying to learn how to use all the array methods instead of always using a for loop. I have searched for array katas on CodeWars to try to get some practice. I think a "next step" would be to learn to combine/string methods together. But, first things first.

Comment: @Janet Combining/chaining them will come natural once you understand them well. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You could use reduce with an implicit casting to number with an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus).

```
sum = array.reduce(function (s, v) {
    return s + +v;
}, 0);
```